# What is the difference between NSFetchedResultsController and NSDiffableDataSourceSnapshot?

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I’m trying to understand the difference between the two in order to understand which to use when deleting, adding, and reloading a row from a UIDiffableTableView. Can someone please explain to me what’s the difference and how to use them?

Comment: A fetched results controller is used with core data. It provides delegate callbacks when a result set changes in core data. You can use these methods to update your views. It has support for diffable data sources. A data source snapshot is used to manage the state of diffable tableViews and collection views. The data in the snapshot doesn't have to come from core data

Comment: Thank you for the response. So, I can just use the data stored in nsfetchedresultscontroller and reload said data through snapshot with the delegate method?

Comment: Also, if I want to delete a row, do I call the managed object’s context delete method and then save through the persistent container? If so, how will fetchedresults controller notified? Or are they already connected somehow?

Comment: If you delete an object and save the context then the fetched results controller will automatically call its delegate

Comment: Yes, I see it now! Thank you so much!